# Gradle Spring Boot Custom Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, configuration

I have an application which uses a mysql database to persist information. I would like to create a version of this application which uses an embedded database (`mariaDB4j`) and add it as a service to our CI environment, so when we launch this embedded version with our end-to-end test, the QA team gets a clean database.

I read a lot about this online, and it looks like gradle configurations are the way to go. The closest I found on this was:

```
sourceSets {
    qaci {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/qa/java'
        }
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.resources
    }
}

configurations {
    qaciCompile.extendsFrom compile
}

bootRepackage {
    customConfiguration = myCustomConfig
}
```

Unfortunately, `bootRepackage` was replaced by `bootJar`. I'm using gradle spring boot plugin `2.0.1.RELEASE`, and when I try to use `bootJar.customConfiguration` I got an error saying that this is an unknown property.

Also, `mariaDB4j` requires a configuration class to work properly, I've included it at `src/qa/java` and created a new source set in order to it be added.

Does anyone knows how to tell the gradle spring boot plugin to use a custom configuration?

Comment: have you got any luck resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using spring profiles?

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

It will allow you to define a different set of values, beans or configuration sets for a handful of profiles (i.e. development, QA, production) and you can use them to run your app with different configurations or different libraries.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("production")
public class ProductionConfiguration {}
```

This class will load all the values you set for that profile in your .properties or .yml file.

And the to run the app you can pass the profile you want to use as command line parameter

```
--spring.profiles.active=dev
```

The configuration for your mariaDB will be under a particular profile.

For example (if you are using yml ):

```
spring:
  profiles: QA
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mariadb://qaserver:1234;databaseName=qaDatabase
    username: USER
    password: PASSWORD
    driverClassName: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    //aditional mariadb properties, configs
spring:
  profiles: production
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://proddatabase:1433;databaseName=production
    username: USER
    password: PASSWORD
    driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Classes and properties belonging to other profiles will not be processed.

Comment: Yes, infact that is what I'm currently using. But Im not really confortable with this code being shipped to production, even if it is not used. If someone decides to change the behaviour of the profile or even remove the annotation, it will have a catastrophic effect. That's why I thought about gradle configs, because than I could store this code in another source set.

Comment: What about writing your own gradle packageJar task? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-repackage-custom-configuration

Comment: Unfortunatelly `BootRepackage` task is not available for Springboot 2.0.1.RELEASE, I explained that on my question

Answer (score 0):

Automatically file system will be created in local path you have provided so you can restore the data while restarting/providing to qa.

**-- Location of db files. delete this directory if you need to recreate from scratch**

```
mariaDB4j.dataDir=./data/local
```

**Default is 3306, so using 3307 just in case it is already running on this machine**

```
mariaDB4j.port=3307
app.mariaDB4j.databaseName=app_alpha
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3307/
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

you can refer this for more information
https://objectpartners.com/2017/06/19/using-mariadb4j-for-a-spring-boot-embedded-database/

Comment: On the link you provided, it specify that you must create a class `EmbeddedMariaDbConfig` in order to it work properly, and that is correct. But what I want to do is to package my production jar without this class, so it does not matter the profile I pick, my production jar will never end up using a embedded database. That's why I looked for gradle source sets. This answer does not tells me how can I build my production jar without the `EmbeddedMariaDbConfig` jar and how to build a dev jar with `EmbeddedMariaDbConfig` on it.